# test cases for hash algorithm anywhere?

Tags: sha256, mining-technical-details, testing

[RFC4231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4231) gives test cases for SHA256 with several different sets of gozintas and gozoutas. I'm looking for something similar for the SHA256 hash as implemented in the Bitcoin mining algorithm.

---

Based on the answers given, here is a very simple test in Python. Note that the generated digest must be reversed before the check, as the 256-bit digest is apparently returned with the least significant bits first.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import hashlib
GENESIS_BLOCK = \
    '0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000' + \
    '000000003BA3EDFD7A7B12B27AC72C3E67768F617FC81BC3888A51323A9FB8AA' + \
    '4B1E5E4A29AB5F49FFFF001D1DAC2B7C01010000000100000000000000000000' + \
    '00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000FFFFFFFF4D04FFFF001D' + \
    '0104455468652054696D65732030332F4A616E2F32303039204368616E63656C' + \
    '6C6F72206F6E206272696E6B206F66207365636F6E64206261696C6F75742066' + \
    '6F722062616E6B73FFFFFFFF0100F2052A01000000434104678AFDB0FE554827' + \
    '1967F1A67130B7105CD6A828E03909A67962E0EA1F61DEB649F6BC3F4CEF38C4' + \
    'F35504E51EC112DE5C384DF7BA0B8D578A4C702B6BF11D5FAC00000000'
GENESIS_HASH = \
    '000000000019d6689c085ae165831e934ff763ae46a2a6c172b3f1b60a8ce26f'
def check_hash(block = GENESIS_BLOCK, blockhash = GENESIS_HASH):
    '''
    check that the calculated hash matches what Bitcoin expects

    >>> check_hash()
    True
    '''
    blockheader = block.decode('hex')[:80]
    header_hash = hashlib.sha256(blockheader).digest()
    check_hash = hashlib.sha256(header_hash).digest()
    return check_hash[::-1].encode('hex') == blockhash

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print check_hash()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, bitcoin uses SHA256d.

Second, the best testcase I can think of is the [genesis block](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Genesis_block):

```
GetHash()      = 0x000000000019d6689c085ae165831e934ff763ae46a2a6c172b3f1b60a8ce26f
hashMerkleRoot = 0x4a5e1e4baab89f3a32518a88c31bc87f618f76673e2cc77ab2127b7afdeda33b
txNew.vin[0].scriptSig     = 486604799 4 0x736B6E616220726F662074756F6C69616220646E6F63657320666F206B6E697262206E6F20726F6C6C65636E61684320393030322F6E614A2F33302073656D695420656854
txNew.vout[0].nValue       = 5000000000
txNew.vout[0].scriptPubKey = 0x5F1DF16B2B704C8A578D0BBAF74D385CDE12C11EE50455F3C438EF4C3FBCF649B6DE611FEAE06279A60939E028A8D65C10B73071A6F16719274855FEB0FD8A6704 OP_CHECKSIG
block.nVersion = 1
block.nTime    = 1231006505
block.nBits    = 0x1d00ffff
block.nNonce   = 2083236893

CBlock(hash=000000000019d6, ver=1, hashPrevBlock=00000000000000, hashMerkleRoot=4a5e1e, nTime=1231006505, nBits=1d00ffff, nNonce=2083236893, vtx=1)
  CTransaction(hash=4a5e1e, ver=1, vin.size=1, vout.size=1, nLockTime=0)
    CTxIn(COutPoint(000000, -1), coinbase 04ffff001d0104455468652054696d65732030332f4a616e2f32303039204368616e63656c6c6f72206f6e206272696e6b206f66207365636f6e64206261696c6f757420666f722062616e6b73)
    CTxOut(nValue=50.00000000, scriptPubKey=0x5F1DF16B2B704C8A578D0B)
  vMerkleTree: 4a5e1e
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take any raw block and its hash as an example. For example, use [the Genesis Block](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Genesis_block):

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

You need to take its header:

> 0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003BA3EDFD7A7B12B27AC72C3E67768F617FC81BC3888A51323A9FB8AA4B1E5E4A29AB5F49FFFF001D1DAC2B7C00

(note the last byte changes from the original `01` to `00`, since block headers don't have transactions in them)

Which hashes to

> 000000000019d6689c085ae165831e934ff763ae46a2a6c172b3f1b60a8ce26f

Comment: Actually, for the block header hash, you only hash up to the nonce, which is 2B7C in this case.